# fineuploader error regarding invalid upload id

Tags: fine-uploader

I upload multiple small and big files (up to 15 of them).  Sizes are from few hundreds KB to 50MB.  I mostly get error can't upload the small file due to '500 (Internal Server Error)' from POST call.  Then I retry to upload that same file but always get the following errors.

....
[Fine Uploader 5.0.3-2] This is an unrecoverable error, we must restart the upload entirely on the next retry attempt.
 [Fine Uploader 5.0.3-2] Problem finalizing chunks for file ID 13 - The specified multipart upload does not exist. The upload ID might be invalid, or the multipart upload might have been aborted or completed.
 [Fine Uploader 5.0.3-2] Server or callback has ordered chunking effort to be restarted on next attempt for item ID 13
.....

Please help if you know what the problem is.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not handling the request to combine chunks correctly.  If [concurrent chunking](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/concurrent-chunking.html) is enabled, or if you've elected to set a ;`chunking.success.endpoint` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#chunking.success.endpoint), Fine Uploader will POST to your server when all chunks have been uploaded successfully for a file.  At that point, you must combine all chunks into one file.  With the concurrent chunking feature turned off, and if the `chunking.success.endpoint` option is not set, Fine Uploader expects you to combine all chunks as part of handling the last chunk's upload POST request.

Either way, your server is not handling this step correctly.  The [server-side guide](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/traditional.html) explains how to handle Fine Uploader's requests.  You can also look at the [server-side examples GitHub repository](https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples).

Comment: I use S3 no server option for uploading.  The other thing is my files are small < 1MB so I believe they're non-chunked.  I narrow it down to upload only small files (8-10) and it always fail with 500 Internal Server Error.